# C# Add app.config settings at runtime in memory

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, runtime, app-config

We have a custom functions library in dll (c# too) that needs to add the following app.config info to the application that references it:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="maxNumberListOfValues" value="5000"/>
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
```

We saw some examples that write a app.config file and then loads it...could it be possible to do it directly in memory? (without writting any files first)

Also take into account that most of the apps will not have a app.config file defined...

Comment: In C#, you can’t achieve this functionality with app.config. Probably you may have to write your own configuration class or you can use .ini file and check it on regular interval.

Comment: @A.P.S the apps are ours and the dll too so the only problem is not having to create a app.config file at runtime, instead only adding those sections to the current application config at memory when the app starts...